# How to show only my content?

Tags: views

I want to make a view that only show the content that is made by the user itself. For example, I have a library and it contains all content that I flagged, but I also want to show all content that I made (even if I have not flagged it).

Answer (score 1):

Use views **CONTEXTUAL FILTERS**, filter by content author is the current user.

Example:

[image]